# How to bypass the check of setuid

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am now taking a security class. And the professor asked us to exploit a program to gain higher privilege.
This is the code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>


    #define BUFSIZE 512

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stat buf;
    char cmd[BUFSIZE];
    FILE *f = NULL;

    if (argv[1] == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please provide an argument\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    if (stat(argv[1], &buf)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't stat the file\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    if (buf.st_gid != getegid()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The file must be owned by group %d\n", getegid());
    exit(1);
    }

    sleep(1);

    if ((f = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open command file\n");
    return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(cmd, BUFSIZE, f)) {
    if ((cmd[0] == '\n') || (cmd[0] == 0x7f)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Found empty line, quitting!\n");
    return 2;
    }
    system(cmd);
    }

    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

The particular situation is:
There is a binary code for this program for us to run. And the SUID of the binary code is set to higher level(here I assume level2). However, buf.st_gid != getegid() will always check if the file we specified is owned by root. Most important thing is, I only have level1 privilege. There is only one file owned by level2 I can use which is provided by our professor. And I certainly tried to pass in that filename. But nothing happens. I don't know if there is anyway I can exploit this program.(To execute some commands during runtime using the privilege of level2)

Comment: The magic words are "race condition".

Comment: What race condition, can you speak more precisely?

Comment: Did they cover https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use in class?

Comment: I have never heard about anything to do with that :(

Comment: I have already solved the problem. Solution is race condition of course.